# About Hessian of distance function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, taylor-expansion

I'm studying the comparison Hessian theorem and I not understand the following:

Let $(M, \langle\ ,\  \rangle)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Given $o\in M$, define $r=dist(o, \cdot)$. Then, for $r \rightarrow 0^{+}$,

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Hess}(r) = \frac1r\bigg\{ \langle\ ,\  \rangle  - dr\otimes dr \bigg\} + o(1).
\end{equation}

I tried use Taylor's formula for $r$. That is, if $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ is a smooth path, such that, $\gamma(0)=o, \ \gamma'(0)=v$ and $\gamma(t)=p$, for some $t\in[0,1]$, then
$$ (r\circ \gamma)(t) = (r\circ \gamma)(0) + (r\circ \gamma)'(0)t + \frac12(r\circ \gamma)''(0)t^2 + o(t^2), $$
i.e.,

$$ r(p) = \langle \nabla r, v\rangle t + \frac12 \operatorname{Hess}(r)(v,v)t^2 + o(t^2). $$

So,

$$ \frac12 \operatorname{Hess}(r)(v,v) = \frac{r}{t^2} - \frac1t \langle \nabla r, v\rangle + o(1). $$

Since $r\rightarrow 0^{+}$, I believe that

$$ \frac12 \operatorname{Hess}(r)(v,v) = \frac{1}{r} \bigg\{ 1- \langle \nabla r, v\rangle \bigg\} + o(1). $$

But, this is no concluded the equality above.

Someone has some idea? Thank you!

Comment: Try thinking about normal coordinates (or geodesic polar coordinates).